# Math journals publishing in Spanish

Tags: journals

There are plenty of good journals that publish papers in French and German. I'm wondering if you know about some reasonable journals that publish papers in Spanish. Thanks.

Comment: Here you have a list of 50 Math Journals publishing in Spanish from Spain and Latinamerica. Some of them are reasonable. This is the link  http://www.journals4free.com/?fq=class:mat&fq=language:spa&p=1

Comment: don't you prefer to make the effort to translate you work in English? compared to the effort that went into your research, I presume this extra effort is small, and it would greatly increase the reach of your work.

Comment: I personally appreciate that there are still some published papers in Spanish.

Comment: The number of citations of the average mathematical pulication is already low enough as it is and if you want to have some impact, then publishing in English will maximize your chances. On the other hand, if the paper is a survey or an invitation to some topic and you want to reach  local audience, then writing in their specific language is better.

Comment: Perhaps students of mathematics would like to read some papers in their own language.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga Thanks! Revista Matemática Iberoamericana is very strong, I didn't know they still publish papers in Spanish.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker That's interesting; you seem to be assuming I need to make an effort to write in English.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva The article is intended for specialists on a problem that we consider to be relevant. I really doubt that the language will make a difference.

Comment: @Maqui, think that you are also restricting the choice of referees. That can work both ways.

Comment: I would personally like to see more mathematical papers in Spanish, but I appreciate I'm in the minority.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the Chilean journal ranking and pulled out those that seem to publish in Spanish.

Boletim da Sociedade Paranaense de Matemática: https://periodicos.uem.br/ojs/index.php/BSocParanMat

Boletín de la Sociedad Española de Matemática Aplicada: https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/revista?codigo=9113

Ciencia, Docencia y Tecnología: https://revistacdyt.uner.edu.ar/

Estudios Pedagógicos: http://revistas.uach.cl/index.php/estped

Revista Colombiana de Estadística: https://revistas.unal.edu.co/index.php/estad

Revista de la Real Academia de Ciencias Exactas, Físicas y Naturales. Serie A. Matemáticas: https://link.springer.com/journal/13398

Revista Integración: https://revistas.uis.edu.co/index.php/revistaintegracion

Revista Matemática Complutense: https://link.springer.com/journal/13163

Revista Matemática Iberoamericana: https://ems.press/journals/rmi

Revista de Educación Matemática: http://funes.uniandes.edu.co/19480/

SCIENTIA, Series A: https://scientia.mat.utfsm.cl/

Boletín de la Sociedad Matemática Mexicana: https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/revista?codigo=19141

Publicacions Matemàtiques: https://mat.uab.cat/pubmat/

Tópicos del Seminario: https://topicosdelseminario.buap.mx/index.php/topsem

Motivos Matemáticos: https://motivos.matem.unam.mx/vol6/num1/

Conference Actas del XIX encuentro de topología; a friend published in Spanish there: https://www.muni.cz/vyzkum/publikace/1168664

Scripta Philosophiæ Naturalis

Pensamiento Matemático

And, I think the best answer was [the first comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426163/math-journals-publishing-in-spanish#comment1095554_426163), which gave a [list of 50 journals that publish in Spanish](http://www.journals4free.com/?fq=class:mat&fq=language:spa&p=1). But, I knew I'd seen some papers in Spanish over the years, wanted to add my own answer, and didn't want this question to linger forever on the unanswered queue.

Comment: Are you sure about the Brazilian journal with a title in Portuguese and the Catalan journal with a title in Catalan? It's credible that either of them might publish in Spanish, but it's not completely obvious. (FWIW all of the titles in their recent editions are in English, so it isn't quite so simple to check).

Comment: @PeterTaylor For each one I pulled from the Chilean list, I went to the journal page, checked the submission guidelines, and if it said "English only" then I cut that one (i.e., most of the Chilean journals). The ones on here either said Spanish was acceptable (yes, including the two you pointed out), or had prior issues (sometimes long ago, like the 80s) that included articles in Spanish. Hope that helps.